# DockerFile for a Python script with Firefox-based Selenium web driver, Flask & BS4 dependencies

Tags: python, docker, selenium, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

Super new to python, and never used docker before. I want to host my python script on Google Cloud Run but need to package into a Docker container to submit to google.

What exactly needs to go in this DockerFile to upload to google?

**Current info:**

- Python: v3.9.1
- Flask: v1.1.2
- Selenium Web Driver: v3.141.0
- Firefox Geckodriver: v0.28.0
- Beautifulsoup4: v4.9.3
- Pandas: v1.2.0

Let me know if further information about the script is required.

I have found the following snippets of code to use as a starting point from [here](https://dev.to/googlecloud/using-headless-chrome-with-cloud-run-3fdp#:%7E:text=The%20phrase%20%22Headless%20Chrome%22%20might,and%20instead%20interacted%20with%20programatically.). I just don't know how to adjust to fit my specifications, nor do I know what 'gunicorn' is used for.

```
# Use the official Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.7

# Install manually all the missing libraries
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils

# Install Chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

# Install Python dependencies.
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . .

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 main:app
```

---

```
# requirements.txt

Flask==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
selenium==3.141.0
chromedriver-binary==77.0.3865.40.0
```

Comment: How do you run your flask application? the docker file seems pretty OK to me, you just pass on all the requirements with specific versioning required. at the end of the file you would add the command which you need to run the flask application, in this docker file gunicorn is being used to serve, you need to add `export FLASK_APP=main` to the dockerfile as well if u have a main.py which contains `app.run()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't even set the main.py to include Flask yet as i'm still learning how... just know i need it. But it will contain `app.run()` so I will add that command. And so i'm understanding correctly, gunicorn is being used as a replacement for Flask in this example?

Comment: The more i read now, the more i'm unsure if i should be using Flask and should use either Nginx or Gunicorn instead.

Comment: Flask apps cam be served with many tools, like `flask run` itself which is not recommended for production usages, we have gunicorn, waitress, wsgi and so on, all of them serve flask apps, you need to tell them in which file you initiated your flask app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gunicorn** is an application server for running your python application instance, it is a pure-Python HTTP server for WSGI applications. It allows you to run any Python application concurrently by running multiple Python processes within a single dyno.

Please have a look into the following Tutorial which explains in detail regarding [gunicorn](https://vsupalov.com/what-is-gunicorn/).

Regarding Cloud Run, to deploy to Cloud Run, please follow next steps or the [**Cloud Run Official Documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#python):

**1) Create a folder**

**2) In that folder, create a file named main.py and write your Flask code**

**Example of simple Flask code**

```
import os

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    name = os.environ.get("NAME", "World")
    return "Hello {}!".format(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

**3) Now your app is finished and ready to be containerized and uploaded to Container Registry**

3.1) So to containerize your app, you need a Dockerfile in the same directory as the source files (main.py)

3.2) Now build your container image using Cloud Build, run the following command from the directory containing the Dockerfile:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/FOLDER_NAME
```

where PROJECT-ID is your GCP project ID. You can get it by running `gcloud config get-value project`

**4) Finally you can deploy to Cloud Run by executing the following command:**

```
gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/FOLDER_NAME --platform managed
```

You can also have a look into the [Google Cloud Run Official GitHub Repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/run/helloworld) for a Cloud Run Hello World Sample.